# XPath запрос для Polyline.Points

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xpath

Помогите составить XPath запрос, уже как день не могу это сделать.

Есть XML

```
<Root>
  <Chart>
    <Title>График 1</Title>
    <Points Color="Black">
      <Point Value="1 1 10 10"/>
      <Point Value="2 2 20 20"/>
      <Point Value="3 3"/>
    </Points>
  </Chart>

  <Chart>
    <Title>График 2</Title>
    <Points Color="Green">
      <Point Value="1 1 10 10"/>
      <Point Value="2 2 20 20"/>
      <Point Value="3 3"/>
    </Points>
  </Chart>
</Root>
```

Нужно сделать запрос который вернет все Point и на основе них построить график.

Я делаю вот так, но в Polyline.Points попадает только первый Point (1 1 10 10) и поэтому в каждом графике рисуется только одна прямая линия.

```
<Polyline Points="{Binding XPath=//Root/Chart/Points/Point/@Value}" />
```

Как сделать так чтоб в график попали все Point, а не только первый ?

Comment: С запросом всё в порядке: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/0842a467faca58bc9d20db92961fa743

Comment: Но поскольку [`Polyline.Points`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polyline.points%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) имеет тип `PointCollection`, странно, что что-то вообще попадает туда без ошибки binding'а.

Comment: PointCollection.Parse(string source) занимается этим, это конвертер по умолчанию для этого типа (TargetDefaultValueConverter), только вот непонятно почему в source приходит только <Point Value="1 1 10 10"/>, а остальное игнорируется

Comment: Ах, вот оно что! Ну, вы можете пустить вместо него свой конвертер, поставить в нём breakpoint, и посмотреть, что в него реально приходит.

Comment: я так и сделал, в него приходят "1 1 10 10", т.е. значения первого Point, а нужно чтоб приходило значения от всех Point "1 1 10 10 2 2 20 20 3 3"

Comment: То есть, приходит _строка_?

Comment: Абсолютно верно, строка.

Comment: Выглядит так, как будто бы для «одиночных» элементов (наподобие `Text` в `TextBox`'е) если `Binding` с `XPath` возвращает несколько элементов, то все, кроме первого отбрасываются. ([пример 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23979348/276994), [пример 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1626352/276994)) Как заставить инфраструктуру понять, что `PointCollection` вполне себе неодиночный элемент, пока не знаю. Решить на уровне XPath через [`string-join`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21996965/276994) не выходит, судя по всему, в WPF не поддерживается XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уфф! Нашёл.

Дело в том, что если `Binding` с `XPath` возвращает несколько элементов, то в некоторых случаях все, кроме первого отбрасываются. (Вот сообщения об этом: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23979348/276994), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1626607/276994)). Участок кода, отвечающий за это, [вот](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Data/ClrBindingWorker.cs,64), и он в самом деле модифицирует `PropertyPath` в зависимости от целевого `DependencyProperty`.

Видно, что если целевое `DependencyProperty` — `DataContext`, то никакой модификации не применяется. Воспользуемся этим:

```
<Polyline DataContext="{Binding XPath=//Root/Chart/Points/Point/@Value}"
          Points="{Binding Converter={StaticResource XmlAttrConcatConverter}}"
          Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeLineJoin="Round"/>
```

Теперь в `DataContext`'е у нас честная коллекция `XmlAttribute`'ов, и чтобы превратить её в строку, воспользуемся конкатенирующим конвертером:

```
class XmlAttrConcatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var attributes = (System.Collections.IEnumerable)value;
        if (attributes == null)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        var typedAttrs = attributes.Cast<XmlAttribute>();
        var result = string.Join(" ", typedAttrs.Select(attr => attr.Value));
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

---

Изучая код в reference source, видно, что модификация не применяется, если прописан нетривиальный property path. Воспользуемся этим для упрощения кода:

```
<Polyline Points="{Binding XPath=//Root/Chart/Points/Point/@Value, Path=.,
                           Converter={StaticResource XmlAttrConcatConverter}}"
          Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeLineJoin="Round"/>
```

Как дополнительный плюс, мы не портим `DataContext`.

---

Заметьте, что без `StrokeLineJoin="Round"` линии выходят за обозначенные им границы.